# MySQL apt/chef installation fails if anything present in /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, chef, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using chef to install the default `mysql-server` package on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm doing it on a server that has no existing MySQL installation, but *does* have `/var/lib/mysql` set up already, as a mounted drive.

Thus, `/var/lib/mysql` has a `lost+found` directory in it.

If I install MySQL using very basic chef:

```
package 'mysql-server'
```

When `/var/lib/mysql/lost+found` exists, I get an error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

(This error also happens if I simply `apt-get install mysql-server`.)

However, if I remove the `lost+found` directory before doing the installation, everything works fine.

I *imagine* that mysql's installation process does something like assuming the `lost+found` directory is actually a database, and tries to upgrade it during the install, or something equally odd.

I've worked around this for now (and also proved to myself that the `lost+found` directory is definitely the cause) by deleting `lost+found` before the install, and recreating it afterwards:

```
directory '/var/lib/mysql/lost+found' do
  action :delete
end

package 'mysql-server'
package 'mysql-client'

execute 'mklost+found' do
  command 'mklost+found'
  cwd '/var/lib/mysql'
end
```

This works fine, but I believe experts would probably rate it at around 8.2 on the standard Kludge-o-Rama scale.

Is there a better way to do the basic, package-default install of MySQL Server on Ubuntu using chef when /var/lib/mysql is already set up as a mounted drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is caused by (a) the existence `/var/lib/mysql/lost+found`, (b) this part of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst`:

```
216     # If database doesn't exist we create it.
217     if [ ! "$(ls -A "${mysql_statedir}")" ] && [ -d "${mysql_filesdir}" ]; then
218       existingdatabase=0
```

where `mysql_statedir` is `/var/lib/mysql`, and (c) Ubuntu's (Debian's) **brain-dead policy** of starting services when the package is installed (but possibly not configured).

Thus the failure to start mysql:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
```

causes dpkg to error out.

So you fixed it by making (a) false. Let's look how you might make (b) or (c) false.

For (b), you can file a bug report saying line 217 of /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst is non-optimal when `/var/lib/mysql` is a separate filesystem so it contains `lost+found`. Maybe it will get fixed.

For (c) you could convince the Ubuntu powers-that-be that starting services on package install is a bad idea. Their retort will be: use policy-rc.d. How would that go?

Create a `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` file that does nothing but return 0 when the init script is `mysql-server`. See the [invokerc.d spec](https://people.debian.org/~hmh/invokerc.d-policyrc.d-specification.txt). However there are other parts of the script that rely on mysql actually starting. The correct code to return isn't 0; maybe 101?. However, any non-zero return code will result in the same outcome you are experienceing now. So policy-rc.d is not helpful to you. /shrug

I hope I have convinced you that your solution is the best.

Comment: Thank you; it's nice to know I wasn't going completely mad, at least!